# Risk of hiding subviews of a iOS standard control

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I want to hide particular subviews inside some iOS standard control. Let's say it's `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *standartPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]];

...

for (UIView *subView in standartPlayer.view.subviews) {
    if (subView.backgroundColor == [UIColor redColor])
        [subView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Let's say again, i could find some views with red background color in `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and hided them.

I didn't use private keys or private class names for finding views. Also this code won't cause crash if Apple changes something with a new version like

```
[[standartPlayer.view.subviews objectAtIndex:12] setHidden:YES];
```

My question is, is this safe enough to pass Apple Review for AppStore?

Comment: It'd probably pass now but there are rumors that Apple is going to begin transparently moving all of the framework-provided view controllers into separate processes, in which case your code would probably crash and burn: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/

Comment: I find that hard to believe since it has too high a likelihood of breaking existing applications.

Comment: @JackLawrence thanks for link, i will check it. But i think i can add extra controls for safety. Also with `view.subViews.count`, this code won't do something that causes crash.

Comment: Yeah you're right, from the article it looks like you can still reference the view. You just won't be able to look at the subviews. Instead, you'll dead-end at a `_UIRemoteView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is, you are not using any private api, or anything related to that. I got some rejections in the App Store, but nothing like that. I would say it's safe, you are just hiding sub-views.

Answer (score 3):

In my original answer, below, I thought you were soliciting information on best practices when hiding/showing subviews.

In retrospect, I'm gathering that you're trying to alter subviews that are built into existing iOS controls. This strikes me as a tad fragile, highly contingent upon the internal structure of the controls which Apple is free to change from one iOS version to another. Personally, I wouldn't be inclined to pursue this technique for this reason alone.

Regarding the Apple app approval process, I am not aware of them rejecting apps for this reason, but wouldn't be surprised if they did. Your concept doesn't run afoul of any specific point in section 10 of [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), but it's also not entirely consistent with the spirit of section 10, either. The app review guidelines are frustratingly ambiguous and subject to change. You're probably fine, but there are no guarantees.

---

A couple of observations regarding best practices when hiding/showing subviews:

1. This sort of thing is unlikely to cause rejection during Apple's app review process. [If you're altering internal subviews of a control, you're probably ok, but I would guess it would depend upon how aggressive you are in that process.]
2. If you find yourself always hiding/showing a bunch of subviews, it's sometimes easier to put them within a container view, and then just hide/show the container.
3. I would discourage you from doing stuff like `objectAtIndex:12` to select particular subview. It's much safer to set the [`tag`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag) property for your subviews and then use [`viewWithTag`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a) when you want to select one (to hide/show, for example).

Comment: Thanks for great info. But i think tags will be private too in my situation. `[standartPlayer.view viewWithTag:51]` can cause rejection.

Comment: @EPyLEpSY - Sorry, I misread your question and have altered by answer accordingly.